# How to return base64Binary from a webservice request (VB.net)?

Tags: vb.net, web-services

How would I return a base64Binary type back from a VB.net web service request?

I would like to return the base64Binary of a PDF document from the binary datatype from SQL Server 2008.

Is base64Binary the same as Byte?
Do I have to convert the Byte to Base64 then to String?

Thankyou!

```
<WebMethod()> Public Function ReturnBase64Something() As ??????????

     Return ????

End Function
```

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Updated question text with 'what I am trying to do'. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just return the binary object and .Net does the rest. Simple.